# Destructuring in ES6. Should I worry?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, undefined, destructuring

Experimenting with destructuring and found that the same code works on stackoverflow and not Codepen (toy gets "undefined"): http://codepen.io/tsalexey544/pen/VjWxmm?editors=0010#

What does it mean? should I worry when using destructuring in my projects?

```js
let obj = {
  species: "Cat",
  // toy: "ball",
}

function whatDoTheyDo ({species, toy = "ball"}) {
  return `The ${species} playes with a ${toy}`
} 

document.write(whatDoTheyDo(obj));
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the Preprocessor to `babel` in CodePen, otherwise it will use standard ES5, where destructuring is not supported.

If you want to use ES6/ES7 features you have to "transpile" your code back to ES5 using certain tools such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Some browsers already support some ES6 features, but full support is still somehow spotty.

Edit - To answer your question: YES, you should worry about serving valid ES5 code, since ES6 is not yet fully supported. At the very minimum you should feed your code to Babel and publish the resulting code, but I strongly suggest looking it [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) and going for a full toolchain

Comment: Seems like that must be a bug in CodePen though - if you set preprocessor to none, surely it should leave the code untouched?  But it seems to write it out as `function whatDoTheyDo({species, toy}) {` - ie missing the default value, so it's done some preprocessing on it, and broken it.

Comment: Should I also set babel on my server? or is ES6 on by default?

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin - Babel shouldn't be server side. It's a transpilation library. It converts ES6 code into ES5 code which gets run in an ES5 compatible browser.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by "on my server", but if you're talking about NodeJS I believe version 6 has very good support for ES6. Still, you might want to transpile if you want to be 100% sure.

Comment: You should setup a development toolchain that lets you write your code in ES6 and either automatically or manually transpiles it to a "distribution" version which is, for all intents and purposes, valid ES5 code. Personally, when writing client-side SPA, I use `webpack` along with `babel` and a bunch of other libs/loaders.

Comment: to view your destructured object in console you could write: console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments[0]));

Comment: Is issue destructuring or default parameters?

Comment: @guest271314 A combination of both - destructuring works, default parameters work; it's when you give a default value to a destructured parameter that it fails - codepen just rewrites the code so it doesn't have the default anymore.

Comment: @JamesThorpe [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RQxlzIK5txI3Eo7PImOP?p=preview) appears to return expected result, though does display a warning at the line.